# Unable to search(crawl) the recently created List item in SharePoint 2010

Tags: searchserviceapplication

I have one library which holds all items. My problem is I'm unable to search the item which is created today but I'm able to find the next day(tomorrow) using search service.

I dint found any error/exception as well in log file. But I have found one message given below

```
11/05/2014 15:24:33.74 w3wp.exe (0x1C8C) 0x08D4 SharePoint Server Search Query dn1p Medium Filter category FASTMaxNumberOfFilters in the config is in wrong format.Input string was not in a correct format. 3eae21a1-8733-4d3b-a578-00bea6ac87aa

11/05/2014 15:24:33.74 w3wp.exe (0x1C8C) 0x08D4 SharePoint Server Search Query dn1p Medium Filter category FASTMaxNumberOfFilters in the config is in wrong format.Input string was not in a correct format. 3eae21a1-8733-4d3b-a578-00bea6ac87aa

11/05/2014 15:24:33.74 w3wp.exe (0x1C8C) 0x08D4 SharePoint Server Search Query dn1p Medium Filter category FASTMaxNumberOfFilters in the config is in wrong format.Input string was not in a correct format. 3eae21a1-8733-4d3b-a578-00bea6ac87aa

11/05/2014 15:24:33.74 w3wp.exe (0x1C8C) 0x08D4 SharePoint Server Search Query dn1p Medium Filter category FASTMaxNumberOfFilters in the config is in wrong format.Input string was not in a correct format. 3eae21a1-8733-4d3b-a578-00bea6ac87aa

11/05/2014 15:24:33.74 w3wp.exe (0x1C8C) 0x08D4 SharePoint Server Search Query dn1p Medium Filter category FASTMaxNumberOfFilters in the config is in wrong format.Input string was not in a correct format. 3eae21a1-8733-4d3b-a578-00bea6ac87aa

11/05/2014 15:24:33.74 w3wp.exe (0x1C8C) 0x08D4 SharePoint Server Search Query dn1p Medium Filter category FASTMaxNumberOfFilters in the config is in wrong format.Input string was not in a correct format. 3eae21a1-8733-4d3b-a578-00bea6ac87a
```

Answer (score 0):

That is the behavior of Search, the Search service crawling will be set to day-end and thus the new items are crawled at the end of the day and can be found the next day.

The Search service defines Crawl Schedules which crawl the site as per defined schedule, so until and unless the crawl is made (either Incremental or Full) the new items will not appear in Search results.

**For SharePoint 2010**

You can minimize the delay between Incremental Crawls but it may affect your server's performance.

```
Go to Central Administration => Application Management => Manage service applications => Search Service Application.

In the Navigation go to Crawling => Content Sources.

You can see the content sources. Edit the content source "Local SharePoint sites" and schedule the crawl. 

Go to ECB menu of Local SharePoint Sites => Edit. 

You can see "Crawl schedule section" where you can schedule the Full Crawl and Incremental Crawl.
```

**For SharePoint 2013**

If you want to have Continuous Crawl schedules, have a look at [Manage continuous crawls in SharePoint Server 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219802(v=office.15).aspx)